# Why is a post with no question or answer not considered spam?

Tags: discussion, flags

I recently registered an SE account, mainly for use in SO, and am trying to pay-it-forward to the community for all the help I've gotten from the site over the years. I've started by posting answers and commenting, then easing into providing edits & flags, etc.

I've read through a number of the threads here on meta in an attempt to learn how to be a more effective contributor but my first experience with attempting to flag [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24161612/jquery-ui-effect-extend-slidefade-effect) as spam faltered and I'd like to learn why.

[This](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251152/3617262) accepted answer on another meta question notes:

`A post should be marked as spam ONLY when it contains an unsolicited advertisement.`

To me, that's exactly what the OP did; they posted an unsolicited advertisement of a jQuery UI extension they built. Does a post need to link to an external site to be considered spam? There is no attempt by the OP to even form a question; it reads essentially as a blog post, not a question. Is SO to be used in this way?

My guess is the answer is 'No' & the question will otherwise be marked as low quality, etc. What I'm looking to learn/understand is what the appropriate flag would have been if not 'spam'.

Comment: .. unclear what you are asking .. -- that is perhaps what you wanted.

Comment: That question should be closed because the question is unclear but it's not spam.  That is an unclear question, not spam.  Spam posts are advertising something - this isn't doing much of anything.

Comment: Except that it isn't a question

Comment: I think I see what Steangelista means, @bluefeet. It kinda takes a hard read, but it does seem to be just an advertisement for using his extension. That said, I think it's not obvious enough to have been flagged as spam. An "Other" flag explaining it might have been better.

Comment: @AndrewBarber When I read it I don't see it as an advertisement for an extension.  To me, it is just unclear what the heck it is - not spam.

Comment: @bluefeet Yeah; I can definitely see it as just plain Unclear, too. It might *really be* intended to be a question.

Comment: It's worth noting that accepted spam flags also make something an audit case, as well as carrying other penalties, so we tend to be a little more strict with those: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160754/why-are-the-moderators-being-so-strict-with-quality-related-flags-recently

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SPAM is reserved to posts that try to promote something (selling a product, getting traffic to a blog/website), and only do that.

The text explaining the spam flag is clear:

> This question is effectively an advertisement with no disclosure. It is not useful or relevant, but promotional.

What was posted can appear as an advertisement, but given that it is fully self contained it is difficult to see what the OP gains from posting it as such. This may be a misguided attempt at self promotion, but might also be a bad attempt at asking a question.

This really looks like the OP decided to use SO as a blog - I wouldn't call this spam, as I don't see anything **promotional** about it, though as something that isn't a question, it doesn't belong either.

A question that is low quality or unclear (ie. wall of code, no context and no *actual* issue posted), is **not** spam.

Comment: Thanks @Oded. In the comments, Andrew Barber seems to agree though that the post is "just an advertisement for using his [the OP's] extension". Your answer seems to suggest that despite that, because it could be useful to someone later, it's not spam. Is that accurate? I'm gather a flag as "Other" with an explanation would've been a better choice here?

Comment: @Stevangelista - it isn't a question, so should be closed, one way or another. If something can be construed as anything **other** than spam, I'd give it the benefit of the doubt.

Comment: Your last edit helps; I got it now, thank you. Essentially, the mods are going to err on the side of caution before flagging something as spam so unless it's blatant, we as users should opt for a different flag and provide an explanation.

Comment: @Stevangelista What about this question makes you think they are promoting a library?

Comment: @Stevangelista - unless there is a clear pattern and it is _clearly_ promotional. In this case, I think the OP was trying to show off their code/jQuery extension. Which is just not what we do.

Comment: @bluefeet - My thought wasn't that they were promoting a library, it was that they were promoting a custom extension they wrote. Basically a "look what I did" post, with no question whatsoever. In hindsight, I should've looked at the OP's profile as links therein to a blog, commercial site, etc would lead me to believe they were trying to build SEO by posting to SO. Absent that, as Oded notes, it's probably just misguided self promotion.

Comment: @Oded, We do that sometimes if we think other people can properly benefit. The difference is we form it into a legitimate question and fit whatever code/knowledge we have to share into a legitimate answer.