# How to share techniques on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, scope, asking-questions

I've shared a technique achievement on Stack Overflow but unfortunately my post was closed by admins. They told me they don't know what I am asking but I'm not asking a question, I just want to share something.

Is there something wrong?

Comment: StackOverflow is a Q&A site, so I don't think it makes sense to post something which doesn't follow that model.

Comment: You can ask and answer your own questions.  If you have an answer to something, simply pose a coherent, well-thought out question, and then answer it appropriately.  Assuming it isn't a duplicate of an existing question, or an extremely trivial question, of course.

Comment: Thanks, but where can I share my codes?

Comment: @WuYangMichael - you can ask a question, and answer it yourself. If the question states the problem that your code is designed to solve, and put your technique as the answer, perhaps?

Comment: StackOverflow isn't a site to just show off code for no reason at all.  If it *really* interests you, post over on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) with the idea of seeking feedback for your code and improvements.

Comment: You can have a github account and share your codes there

Comment: fyi, if you weren't aware http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260187/why-is-a-post-with-no-question-or-answer-not-considered-spam (assume that's the same question)

Answer (score 12):

If the technique is useful to you in solving a specific problem, then write up a question that describes this problem and asks how to solve it. Then answer it.

[There's even a handy checkbox to help you with this...](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/05/encyclopedia-stack-exchange/)

Just make sure you don't get so focused on your solution that you forget to tuck it under [a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)!

Comment: Thanks a lot! just focus on how to solve questions.