# How should I have handled what looked like spam answers?

Tags: discussion, spam

[This guy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/350129/neel) seems to be regurgitating at-best-sketchy answers to simple questions answered long ago, along with links to his favorite website.  After I saw three or four of them I looked at his page and it seems it's all he's been been doing for days, and all the answering he's ever done except one from three years ago.

The answers I flagged are all deleted but one, that one had the link edited out, and all the flags were declined.

Here's a sample of dozens of similar answers:

> We can find the permutation of a string by using recursion.
>
> - Take the first character of the input string.
> - Permute all the characters in the remainder of the string recursively and create a new array with them.
> - Add the first character into each possible position of the new array and return.
>
> For example and code http //www.algoqueue.com/algoqueue/default/view/6684672/print-permutation-of-a-string

Should I have just gone ahead and edited out all the links, or what?  None of the ones I looked at for any length of time contributed anything to speak of.

Comment: I see bluefeet is working his way through his answers.  My 2 cents is your flags were correct.  The user, while providing some valid answers, was linking to his profile everywhere, which is not generally considered acceptable.

Comment: I guess some moderators would handle such flags differently. I've seen another moderator mark such flags as helpful, then proceed to delete the flagged answer, instead of editing out the (arguably spam) link.

Comment: @Cupcake Spam links should never be edited out of posts.  It just makes work harder for the mods and community to deal with them.  Spam-deleted posts are automatically redacted by the SE software.

Comment: Seems like all this whack-a-doodle does is copy/paste answers from another website.

Comment: I ask this question out of pure ignorance. Why would anyone want to behave like this on a serious website? I've been a large contributor on a language website in the past, and behavior similar to this would get the user banned (can't login, ip address blocked).

Comment: I found myself in a similar situation to you before, so this might be relevant: [How is this not spam?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251150/how-is-this-not-spam)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Raising a flag for the moderators is correct, however, you incorrectly flagged these answers as spam. Spam flags have harsh penalties to users so we are very selective when we accept them.

Spam flags should be used for the following:

> This answer is effectively an advertisement with no disclosure. It is not useful or relevant, but promotional.

In my opinion, the user was attempting to answer the questions and instead of including the code they included a link to the code - which was wrong, but not spam.

If you find yourself in this situation again, all you need to do is use a custom flag on a single answer by the user explaining the issue similar to "This user's answers include a link to an outside website in most/all of the answers."

Feel free to use your edit power to remove the links, comment to the user, vote, etc. if you think any of their answers are deserving of these actions.

Comment: Okay, so do I have it right below, that [a spam flag isn't any kind of warning at all, but a foad](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260524/how-should-i-have-handled-these/260525#comment42535_260525)?  I promise that's my last on this, it's already taken up way too much of everyone's time, and thank you.

Comment: @jthill Use spam flags for actual advertisements, users get hit with a big penalty for spamming which is partly why we are careful with them.   Another thing to keep in mind, when you find a pattern just flag once, we don't need 10+ flags on the same issue.  But you did the right thing in flagging, you just used the wrong flag. :)

Comment: I want to point out that this user has been posting links to http://www.algoqueue.com/ since the start of June. According to [AlgoQueue's About page](http://www.algoqueue.com/algoqueue/default/about), they launched May of this year. It appears to be a Q&A site like Stack Overflow, but tailored to algorithms. They also run ads on the site. Most of the linked posts I've seen are by "indrani", who according to LinkedIn, [is a technical writer there](https://www.linkedin.com/groups/AlgoQueue-8105248). She also may be based out of New York, where this "Neel" user says he's from in his profile.

Comment: I could be wrong, but all of this strongly suggests undisclosed spam advertising to me.

Comment: If someone is posting answers with the main aim of promoting a link to a website that they run or are involved with, surely that *is* spam. It is *effectively* an advertisement, as the subtext says, and should be flagged as such

Comment: @bjb568 was editing this post for an apostrophe really needed?

Comment: @RUJordan I was just seeing how people would react :)

Comment: Created a new question [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260638/what-is-the-exact-definition-of-spam-for-so) to discuss whether this should be considered spam or not. In my opinion this clearly qualifies as "unsolicited advertisement" just with a little spin to make it a bit less obvious.

Answer (score 9):

I see bluefeet is working her way through his answers. My 2 cents is your flags were generally correct, but there may be side issues depending on the type of flag you chose. The user, while providing some valid answers, was linking to his profile everywhere, which is not generally considered acceptable.

In response to your edit, what flag did you choose?

IF you picked Spam or Not An Answer, they it makes sense they were declined because those types of flags have specific meanings that impact other aspects (such as the spam filter and review audits).  When you see someone acting in such a manner, it is often better to flag a single answer with a custom "other" flag and explain the situation, rather than flagging several different answers with "Not an Answer"

Comment: Ahem... working _her_ way through this...

Comment: @bluefeet I always assumed you were male `:/`

Comment: I would have flagged as spam. It looks like an attempt to gain clicks to http://www.algoqueue.com/, and honestly, some (if not most or all) of the answers are ***really bad***, like [this one with no explanation, just code dump](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24208401/456814).

Comment: You know what they say about assumptions, @Cupcake...

Comment: ...they can be embarrassingly inaccurate.

Comment: Spam - fig-leaf content covering for what I thought was plainly an advertising link.  What did I miss?

Comment: @jthill looked like advertising to me too...

Comment: @bluefeet fixed, my apologizes

Comment: @psubsee2003 No worries. :)

Comment: @jthill the problem is the spam flag is for obvious advertisement - such as "hey go buy your gucci bags here".  Less obvious stuff often needs an "other" flag, plus where [bluefeet said](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260527/250725)

Comment: Okay: spam isn't any kind of a warning, it's a foad.

Comment: @Blastfurnace Unfortunately we have 1.4k+ flags in the queue so it takes some time to get to "Other" flags but we will act on them when we hit them.  Also remember that if you have edit privileges you can always edit the answers to remove the link, etc. :)

Comment: @Blastfurnace Nope you did the right thing, "Other" flag explaining the issue.  Just offering up some additional suggestions that could be used to help us out.

Comment: @jthill the spam flag carries a -100 rep penalty, so it can be somewhat unfair to someone who is trying to be somewhat helpful and has otherwise tried to contribute to the community.  It also feeds the internal spam filter so erroneous "helpful" flags by mods can alter the way the system works

Comment: I really feel like there should be more obvious indications of the SO definition of "spam". I know it says "effectively an advertisement with no disclosure", but a lot of people just read the titles, and "spam" has morphed to mean more than just "buy v1agr1", but also "asdlfasdfhaoeur1f9u8d3 lul lul lul" (on a lot of sites, that aren't this one).

Comment: Not sure that removing the link is a good idea: at least in the example given that would make it a complete non-answer. Might as well delete the whole answer in that case.

Comment: @WGroleau If removing the link makes it not an answer - then flag as not an answer.

Answer (score -9):

**Flags have big impact on the flagged person**

There are serious punishments for getting flagged (as I've heard) and it's best to only flag it if it's a troll answer or something irreverent to the question. I shall give a crappy example:

Q: How do I make a variable in Javascript?

A: just put the code line var in ur script it will make varible

*That's not helping anyone, so flag it and do us all a favor.*

Whereas is he kindly stated and **in detail** explained how to make a variable in javascript, as so:

A: You make a variable by putting var at the start of the variable, then make it look something like this:

```
var name = myName(name) {
<code here>;
};
```

Remember, the semicolons are important!

*THAT'S AN ANSWER. THAT'S WHAT SHOULD BE ON STACKOVERFLOW.* 
So next time you want to flag an answer, make sure it doesn't work or there isn't enough detail beforehand, don't just flag posts willy-nilly because they are short and you think they are spam.

Comment: _"That's not helping anyone, so flag it and do us all a favor."_ Uhhh. No. The example you posted is an example of a _bad_ answer, but still an attempt at an answer that diamond mods are unlikely to delete. _"...make sure it doesn't work or there isn't enough detail beforehand..."_ _Do not_ flag an answer because it is wrong or poorly written. If it is an attempt to answer the question and not spam, then the worst you should do it downvote and possible comment to explain what is wrong with the answer.

Comment: [This FAQ post should explain that a little better than I did.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-it-is-not-an-answer) Please, take the time to read through it.