# When to flag an answer as "not an answer"

Tags: discussion, support, faq, flags, not-an-answer

With respect to some flag rejection messages I received recently, the following seems to be a few of the guidelines for judging an answer:

- If it's an incorrect answer, downvote it.
- If you don't agree with it, downvote it.
- Flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies or an altogether wrong answer.

According to these guidelines, it looks like every answer which is not spam, offensive, abusive or hate speech is an answer.

So I was wondering:

- When should an answer be flagged as "not an answer"?
- Is it actually used?
- If it is actually used, then for what kind of answers?

[Return to FAQ index](/q/251225)

Answer (score 405, accepted):

## What To Flag as Not An Answer (NAA)

You flag as NAA things posted as answers that ***clearly and obviously* do not attempt to answer an on-topic question or the question asked**. If the fact that the answer isn't an attempt to answer isn't *clear and obvious*, without reading the question body, then instead of an NAA flag an "in need of moderator intervention" flag should be raised and you should explain the issue in more detail.

### Examples of things to flag as NAA

None of the following are answers, nor are they spam or offensive. You'd be surprised how often these types of posts crop up.  Common examples of what to flag are:

#### Thanking the posters

> Thxs! I had teh exact same poblem and this page really hepped me (sic)

or

> @username's solution worked. Thanks!

"Thanks" can be expressed by upvoting the post and/or accepting the answer. Even as a comment, "thanks" is subject to deletion.

#### Asking a new question

> So how do I apply this to the frobnar when I twiddled the foozbain then?

If a user has a new question, then they should use the "Ask Question" button to post a new question. Obviously, a question would need to be fleshed out more than just what's in this example.

#### Asking for clarifications

> I don't get it; you want to foo the bar, but you did not include a traceback. Can you add that to your question, please?

Such requests should not be posted as answers, but as comments.

#### 'Bumping' the question

> Man, I have the exact same problem, have you got a solution for this yet?

The preferable way to increase the visibility of a question is to offer a [bounty](/help/bounty).  Posting a non-answer just adds clutter and should never be done.

#### Links to an answer

Essentially this:

> [image: An answer with score −2, with the contents: ‘i think you should take The tutorial HERE! This will help you a lot’. The first sentence is a link.]

If there's nothing *in the answer itself* to *actually answer the question*, then it's not an answer and should be deleted. In other words:

> The answer can be found over here: <link>

**Notice that this is not necessarily the same thing as a "link-only answer"** (although there is much overlap). In particular, answers where the link *itself* is the answer to the question are excluded and should not be flagged. For example, where the link text is a function/API and the link target is the associated documentation, or where [the answer explains how to form a URL correctly](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355035/first-post-review-audit-thought-the-answer-was-link-only-when-a-url-was-the-a/355037#355037).

[A handy rule-of-thumb is to strip the markup](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer): if it's still an (attempted) answer without the link, then it's an answer and should not be flagged.

[image: What is an answer vs what's not using apples and oranges as examples]

If you find an especially useless link-only answer, such as one with a *dead* link, it is better to use the "requires moderator attention" flag so you can *explain* to the moderators why the post should be deleted. Don't leave moderators guessing; be explicit, rather than using a generic "not an answer" (NAA) flag. Do this *only* if you cannot improve the post yourself and the only possible solution is deletion. Examples of ways to fix a low-quality link-only answer are:

- Editing in the pertinent information from the link. Try to *summarize* the information in your own words and [quote relevant parts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing).

  (Do not copy in code from GitHub Gists or other sources where the license is incompatible with our CC BY-SA license. Only the original owner of the content can cross-license it, so they need to be the one to edit. This is a good case to raise a custom moderator flag, or to leave a comment.)
- Replacing the link with the page's new location or with [an archived copy](https://archive.org/).
- Leaving a comment informing the poster of the problems with the answer and politely asking them to fix them. (This is especially appropriate for old answers, posted by still-active users, that were once useful but haven't aged well.)

## What NOT To Flag

Any post that attempts to answer the question — however badly — is still an answer and should not be flagged. You can add comments or downvote such answers as a signal that they are bad answers and not useful, but they are *still answers*.

- **Wrong answers**. Moderators do not judge the technical correctness of answers.
- **Answered in the wrong programming language**. Answers in a different programming language are still answers.
- **Answers on off-topic questions**. If the *question* is the problem, there is no reason for wasting flags and time on its constituents. For example: a link-only answer with a recommendation in response a question asking for recommendations.  If you have [the privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions), vote to close the question, otherwise flag it.
- **Short answers**.  The difference between comments and answers is *not* their length.  Concise attempts to answer the question are answers.
- **Answers phrased as suggestions**. Answers that say "Maybe you should try X" or "I don't know if this will work, but..." are still answers. Instead of flagging them, edit them to remove the uncertainty.
- **Answers with *no* code**. Answers with no code are still answers.
- **Answers with *only* code**. Answers with only code are still answers.

Comment: Links to documentation aren't automatically valid answers. "use [printf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf)" is a bad answer, but "look [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf)" is not an answer at all. CppReference could be down.

Comment: All the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) says is "**Answer the question**: Read the question carefully. What, specifically, is the question asking for? Make sure your answer provides that – or a viable alternative. The answer can be “don’t do that”, but it should also include “try this instead”. Any answer that gets the asker going in the right direction is helpful, but do try to mention any limitations, assumptions or simplifications in your answer. Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better."

Comment: Why is a link only answer ever acceptable? "The answer can be found here: (link-official-docs)" still has the issue that the answer does not stand on its own if the link is removed or if link goes bad. "Q: Why is X a security risk?", "A: link1, link2, link3" is apparently ok? "Q: How do I do X?", "A: Link1, Link2, Link3?" is not deleted. As for requiring me to improve the answer. IMO that is nice but not my responsibility.  My goal is to inform the answerer there answer is unacceptable so they can do better in the future, not to let them soil the site and clean up after them.

Comment: Should you let the person know that his answer is better suited as a comment and politely ask them to delete it?

Comment: @Yatin: the majority of accounts that do this can't comment. If a post is deleted, the blue banner at the top links to the help centre outlining why the post was deleted, so feedback is already provided. So leaving a comment usually won't achieve much.

Comment: "*Any post that attempts to answer the question—however badly—is still an answer!*" - What is here the criteria for an "attempt" exactly? What if you have an answer which does not even answer the question at all; not even by an "*attempt*"?

Comment: Also two sentence later "*Moderators do not judge the technical correctness of answers.*" - How can one know if an answer attempts to answer the question if s/he do not judge the technical correctness at least a little if it answers the question?

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio: The fact that it isn't the role of a moderator to maje such judgement does not mean it isn't the role of users in general, domain experts in particular, and very importantly - the OP themselves. Naturally, the OP, while somewhat biased, is the most likely person to flag a supposed answer as not an answer when they (ugh, pronouns, pronouns) believe their question has not been answered.

Comment: What if it's a link to an image of code (eg. imgur, user not having enough [reputation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307503/11682469) to embed the image)? Eg. something like "Try this: enter image description here." Most of the reasons that apply to [questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/11682469) also seem to apply to answers (eg. screen readers).

Comment: @JeanneDark: that's 'very low quality', provided the contents of the image should have been posted as text. If the image shows you where to click in the UI of a tool, or similar, just edit the post to embed the image.

Comment: If the answerer misread the question and answer a thing the asker doesn't need, then would that answer be deleted? Downvote seems to be for wrong answer. Misreading answer isn't wrong though

Comment: @Ooker: if the answer is not helpful to you, a downvote would apply. Vote for _usefulness_, The tooltips on the voting buttons explicitly say this: the downvote button tooltip says: *This answer is not useful*.

Comment: If you cannot post links in answers then can you just copy paste or write in your own words what is written in the article?

Comment: Is it acceptable to use an answer to post relevant non-answer things that do not neatly fit into a comment? (For instance: questions or relevant concerns that are too long to fit into a comment and would be messy as multiple comments, or questions/concerns that involve blocks of code that would not neatly format in a comment?)

Comment: @EdwardPeters No. Answers are for *answers*, period. Not for clarification requests, not for invitations for discussion, etc. The rule of thumb: if the text suggests further interaction with the question asker, what you are posting is probably NAA. If comments end up being too messy, invite the user to chat.

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine Alright. Does something of the form "Whatever approach you take, you will need to watch out for..." (or similar relevant information/context) qualify as a partial answer or attempt at an answer?

Comment: @EdwardPeters it's situational. Partial answers are a murkier territory, but one rule stands always true: the answer *must* address the question's concern at least partially ("regarding the X error you get...", for example) to be considered one. Otherwise, we'd have to allow everyone to make unrelated commentary because it might come up on any question. We need focused Q&As.

Comment: Of note is that there is a difference between what is considered *acceptable* and what can be *flagged as NAA*. The problem here is that moderators are often not subject matter experts, so the current stance (not all of the mods feel that way, but many) is that NAA flags should not be used if an answer *resembles* an answer to the question and be reserved for blatant non-answers (bare links, "thank you" and "I have the same problem" posts as such). At least that's the case for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Just a note that this answer encompasses the following question on Meta: [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/596550)