# How to treat open source repository promotion?

Tags: discussion, flags

Recently I stumbled upon a user, who copied and pasted an answer which was promoting his open source repository. He did it with multiple questions with the same tag related to his repository. It was about a PDF generation API.

All his answers were like "I did [this](http://example.com) repository, check it out, maybe it would help".

How should I treat such answers?

Should I Flag one of the copied and pasted answers as spam? It looks much more like a link-only answer. But due to the copy and pasting it also kind of looks likes promotion.

Should I Flag it for moderator intervention? Is this an appropriate problem to contact a moderator about? I guess the community could handle this by itself.

Should I Flag as not an answer? It looks like the most relevant flag. But each of his copy and pasted answers need this flag and this still might not stop him from doing it again.

What is the best option?

Comment: I'd flag for moderator intervention and let them sort it out.  No need to tag more than one.  If you're on the fence about whether this requires moderator attention you can link to a comment here and ask for the consensus .

Comment: If someone is copying and pasting the exact same answer with a link-only answer, i do believe it qualifies as Spam, but since it isn't obvious spam, you'd have to do an "other" flag and explain the situation with at least 1 link

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If it's actually a straight copy-paste there will be an automatic flag for a mod, so you don't really *have* to do anything, a mod will most likely end up seeing it even if nobody does anything.  If the answers are pretty much the same, but not *quite* the same, or they're old enough that you think that the auto flag may have been missed, or if you just really want to I guess, then you can cast your own flag.  Take your pick of any number of the following:

1. It is, as you said, Not An Answer.
2. It's posting duplicate answers, which is virtually always a sign that the questions are duplicates or that the answers don't answer the question; consider flagging the questions as duplicates if they are, and also flag the answers as duplicates so the mod can act accordingly.
3. It also does look like spam, since they're there to promote a product, although since it's likely not obvious when looked at in isolation, I'd go with a custom flag explaining why you think it's spam over a spam flag.

Feel free to use any or all of those.

Comment: It was straight copy-paste.

Comment: The spam flag doesn't seem like it'd fit here, but NAA/close other questions as a dupe would be appropriate.

Comment: @Makoto It *is* spam, although I agree that I'd go with a custom mod flag to explain why it's spam, because I feel that it merits more explanation than just "it's spam".

Comment: `It is, as you said, Not An Answer` what about if the code at the link does help with the problem? Wouldn't that make it an answer, albeit a bad one bordering on spam?

Comment: No, @steve, because the purported answer does not actually contain an answer. At best, it contains a pointer. We don't consider indirect answers to be answers. If edited to include the relevant portions of the code, it might *become* an answer, though, so editing would be a fourth option.

Answer (score 3):

> How should I treat such answers?

**Check the question *first***! Questions that tend to be lighting rods for those kind of answers are a more pressing problem, since even if you deal with the problematic answer, it will just accumulate cruft overtime; effectively wasting moderating resources. Once you've identified that the question is the problem, flag/vote to close (I would recommend drawing attention to it), then move onto something else. Remember that closed questions are qualified for deletion, after which would make all associated problems moot.

Now, lets presume that the question isn't a problem. Copying existing content and appending a link is a [known technique employed by spammers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260524/792066), so in those cases, I tend to be strongly biased towards flagging as spam.