# Is a question promoting code the OP wrote spam?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, specific-question, spam

I was reviewing [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67233828/airflow-task-decorator-sample) and promptly flagged it as spam due to the fact that it is promoting code the OP wrote.

Now, however, I'm not too sure if I made the right decision. Obviously, it's not a question and thus deserves to be closed, but was spam the right flag? Or would a simple 'Needs Details or Clarity' suffice?

Comment: it's just not a question. Questions generally will have code the OP wrote, so that alone certainly doesn't make it spam

Comment: @KevinB But the difference is that it's promoting the code, saying "I hope it is helpful".

Comment: Right... but... it's not promoting any code. it's not trying to boost views on anything the user owns, it's just something they're providing to try to be helpful.... unfortunately in a way that doesn't follow the guidelines.

Comment: @KevinB ok time to retract my flag then. Thanks for the guidance.

Comment: I'm really confused. I think there's a disagreement on the question poster's intent. There's no indication this was meant to be an answer. It reads as one of those typical "I have no idea how to use this website" types of posts that is certainly well-intentioned but is, indeed, spam. It doesn't ask a question, there is _absolutely zero_ indication it is trying to answer someone else's question, on its own it provides little to no value and would be a poor candidate for a Q&A (self-answer) post. I'm not sure when the precendent for SO shifted to allowing 'whatever, man', but this isn't The Way.

Comment: @Qix-MONICAWASMISTREATED the post isn't allowed. but it also isn't spam. Spam flags have quite heavy penalties that this user doesn't deserve.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

No, this is not spam. A post promoting code is very much par for the course on SO. After all, that's what answers are; a "promotion" of some code that solves a problem, and that seems to be the intent of the OP's post. For a post to be spam, there needs to be some product/service/library/etc being promoted. A small snippet of code doesn't qualify.

The issue with the question you linked is that the code being promoted is in the wrong place; it should have been in an answer instead. As it stands, with the code in the question, it doesn't fit the Q&A format, and should just be closed.

Comment: Instead of downvoting and closing, why couldn't we just talk with the OP and put the code in an answer and then rewrite the question? It would have been useful knowledge, but now it's just yet another closed question. The OP was tryna be helpful, but was met with downvotes.... 6 of them, which is pretty harsh on the main site.

Comment: @10Rep That's definitely a possibility, and I added a comment suggesting to the OP that they make a self-answered question. I'm not comfortable enough with the subject matter to actually make those edits myself, but someone who knows the subject could certainly do that. I agree the downvotes are a bit harsh (and in fact the effort put in should attract *some* upvotes, I would think), but a lot of the downvotes (for better or worse) are a result of the Meta effect though, and there's not much that can be done about that.

Comment: @10Rep The question being closed doesn't stop that rewrite from taking place; it can and should still happen. The post is off-topic as currently formatted and it should be closed as a result, plain and simple, even if it could be edited into shape in the future.

Comment: @zcoop98 I would agree, but the thing is to be realistic, reopening happens rarely, and the post has 6 downvotes. I just find it really unlikely that even after the edit, it will get a positive score and a reopen....

Comment: @10Rep I'm sympathetic to that viewpoint; reopening a post can be quite hard. However, I would rather risk it not being reopened once edited into shape, as opposed to leaving it open, and it never being fixed. FWIW, I'm following the question, and if it does get edited, I'll be more than happy to cast a reopen vote myself.

Comment: @10Rep (@cigien) it's hard to say for sure, but it seems that the OP actually [***has*** a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67131877/dynamically-generated-schedule-interval) that most likely this should have been an answer to...

Comment: @Tomerikoo Oh, good point. I'm not sure either, but it might be worth leaving a comment on the post, asking if the other post is actually an answer to the question.

Comment: I think the OP got confused and didn't realise that you can add an answer to a question (especially a self answer). That would explain it.

Comment: "Spam" is not limited to "buy my product". We're arguing semantics at this point. The OP here is trying to ask how to classify a question that is, quite clearly, a poor fit for the site. Starting an answer with "this is not spam" is a gross misrepresentation of what we're after here. This entire thread is a trip. There'd be no question about this 10 or even 5 years ago.

Comment: @Qix-MONICAWASMISTREATED I can't speak for what the norm was 5 or 10 years ago, but my understanding is that the linked question should *not* be flagged as spam, and that a mod would decline a spam flag on that question. Yes, the question is a poor fit for the site, but there are VLQ and other flags for that; a spam flag should not be raised because of that.

Comment: VLQ is due to poor formatting. Spam is unwanted content. The question is clearly trying to post "helpful" code in a way that demonstrates they do not understand the website. Their intention is not to participate in Q&A, but instead to misuse a feature and contribute to the noise. This is 100% spam.

Comment: @Qix-MONICAWASMISTREATED If you feel that a spam flag is warranted on that question, go ahead and raise one, that's your prerogative. I would also suggest writing an answer to this Meta question stating your POV, so that other users can give feedback on whether that's appropriate, or not.

Comment: @Qix-MONICAWASMISTREATED - I've been a user on the site for over 11 years. I can't remember any time when I would have considered that question "spam". Unwanted content, sure... downvote and close it, sure... but it's not really spam nor would it ever have been. The user was not advertising a product, website, book or even himself. His profile is nearly blank. He was sharing a helpful code snippet in good faith, but misunderstood the Q/A format. That's not spam by any reasonable definition.

Comment: I say this because the spam flag has special meaning and, given too many spam flags, his account would be at risk for permanent closure. That's a bit harsh for just wanting to share something he struggled over and thought others would find useful.

Comment: Further justification from 2014: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251152/211627. Spam is a very specific type of unwanted content. If we redefined it to mean _any_ unwanted content, then it'd be too broad to be useful.